# jboss-all.xml JBoss EAP 6.4 not taken in consideration (not working)

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have a JBoss EAP 6 instance, which has a couple of deployments (An EAR and a few WARs):

The thing is that on shutdown, I need `myWar1.war` to be undeployed after `myEar.ear`, but the actual result is that `myEar.ear` is being undeployed last, causing errors in the logs on shutdown due to the dependency.

I've already tried declaring dependencies of that war to the ear through `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, and `myWar1.war/WEB-INF/jboss-all.xml`. Here are the examples:

#### myWar1.war/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="deployment.myEar.ear">
        <imports>
            <exclude path="***" />
        </imports>
    </module>
    <module name="javax.annotation.api" />
</dependencies>
```

#### myWar1.war/WEB-INF/jboss-all.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
        <dependency name="myEar.ear" />
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

None of these solutions seem to work. Although, it looks like `jboss-all.xml` is being read and parsed by JBoss, but it makes no effect on the order of undeployment of the dependant WAR on the EAR. (I guess it's not the expected behaviour, as states [HERE](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/88763).)

All the WARs are being deployed through JBoss CLI (then the server is restarted), but the `myEar.ear` is being exploded inside the server `/deployments`, and it's also added as a deployment through the CLI. Here are the entries for that in `standalone-full.xml`.

Also, the WAR is a SpringBoot application, built and packaged by Maven.

#### standalone-full.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
    <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-enabled="false" scan-interval="5000"/>
</subsystem>
<deployments>
    . . .
    <deployment name="myWar1.war" runtime-name="myWar1.war">
         <content sha1="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    </deployment>
    <deployment name="myEar" runtime-name="myEar.ear">
         <fs-exploded path="$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/myEar.ear"/>
    </deployment>
    . . .
</deployments>
```

Is there another way I can alter the undeployment sequence when shutting down JBoss? Is there a way to make jboss-all.xml be recognized properly by JBoss, or I am missing some configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The deployment dependencies tag in jboss-all.xml is usually [referenced only for ensuring applications deploy](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Control_the_order_of_Deployed_Applications_on_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform.html) after dependencies are established (As in your example myear has to be deployed before mywar1 deploys) but not for shutdown.

Commonly JBoss' command line commands (look up JBoss CLI) are used to handle startup, deployments and shutdowns, but the CLI is not meant to be invoked from within your program's code. There is a parallel api called the Management API, for the management interface, which has shutdown/startup functionality, and which is meant to be called from within your code.

The AS7 Management API is applicable to the JBoss EAP 6.x, as should the newest Wildfly version of the API. Only the wildfly api is supposed to be the most updated page for the API and it lists the startup/shutdown procedures though YMMV. Here is [the wildfly API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Suspend%2C+Resume+and+Graceful+shutdown) and the [6.x/AS7 api](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/The+HTTP+management+API) in case you run into issues using the wildfly reference. Here is how to use the [Management Interface API programmatically.](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/using-jboss-management-api-programmatically)

Comment: This answer relies heavily on the content of external links. Should they ever become invalid, the answer would lose a lot of value. Can you please [edit] it and add at least a summary of what can be found there? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've expounded a bit, is this a better answer or should I add more still?